# Присвоить NSMutableAttributedString в массив для последующего вывода в tableView Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Здравствуйте!
Собрал строку из NSMutableAttributedString. Была необходимость дать отдельным элементам строки свой цвет. Строка работает, а вот к массиву я не могу ее добавить и передать для считывания tableView.
Если я использую array = append(string.MutableString as String), она присваивается, но! аттрибуты(цвет текста), не передаются....
Смысл в том, что бы отображать в клетке tableView строку с элементами разного цвета.

Comment: Создайте массив с элементами Any. let array = [Any](). Далее добавть туда NSMutableAttributedString. И при получении строки, конвертируйте  Any в NSMutableAttributedString. Это как идея, я не могу сказать точно, будет ли работать.

Comment: Ха! Лол! Работает! Вы гений! Правда я создал массив NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь!